# English translation of Lambert's Theorie der Parallellinien?

Tags: translation, ho.history-overview, geometry

Does anyone know if there is an available (published or unpublished) English translation of Johann Lambert's *Theorie der Parallellinien*?  I was able to find it online in German by way of the bibliography of Jeremy Gray's *Worlds out of Nothing* at [this link](http://openlibrary.org/books/OL23347640M/Die_theorie_der_parallellinien_von_Euklid_bis_auf_Gauss), but I have been unable to find it in English.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The place to go for everything related to Lambert is 
[this one](http://www.kuttaka.org/~JHL/Werke.html). 
Asking Maarten Bullynck, the author of this web site, might be
a good idea.

Comment: Thanks, Franz!

Maarten Bullynck directed me to "From Kant to Hilbert" by William Ewald.  In the first volume (pp. 152-167), the first ten or so pages of Lambert's paper are translated by Ewald himself.  Ewald's introductory essay is also really interesting.

I'm continuing to research, but I've yet to find a full translation of Lambert's essay on parallels into English.  I'll post something here if anything turns up.

Answer (score 7):

Vincenzo de Risi of Max Planck Institute (https://www.mpiwg-berlin.mpg.de/en/users/vderisi) is preparing an English edition of this paper to be published by Springer.

Comment: I appreciate this new piece of information! Thanks for sharing the news. I'm glad that this project is being taken up.